# How to use the OpenPose Python API in Google Colab?

Tags: python-3.x, computer-vision, google-colaboratory, pose-estimation, openpose

I'm new to Computer Vision and Python in general. I'm trying to figure out how to extract the keypoints for a person from an image and then feed them to a Deep Learning model which will detect if the pose is suspicious or not. For detection of keypoints I've come across OpenPose's Python API but it requires an Nvidia GPU which I don't have. How can I run the OpenPose Python API on Google Colab?

Answer (score 0):

You may git clone the repo to colab workspace.
You might need to modify some dependency files to get it running on it.

The changes to make it running is too broad to discuss here.